# How to retrieve the optional claims of enterprise connection(azure app)

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, auth0, auth0-connection

[in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) its mentioned how it can add optional claims to an azure application

so I enabled the ***family_name***, ***given_name*** in following way

[image]

then how It can retrieve this in the application side?

in auth0 sample application it's sharing the following details only

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "reactstrap";

import Highlight from "../components/Highlight";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";
import { useAuth0, withAuthenticationRequired } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

export const ProfileComponent = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth0();

  return (
    <Container className="mb-5">
      <Row className="align-items-center profile-header mb-5 text-center text-md-left">
        <Col md={2}>
          <img
            src={user.picture}
            alt="Profile"
            className="rounded-circle img-fluid profile-picture mb-3 mb-md-0"
          />
        </Col>
        <Col md>
          <h2>{user.name}</h2>
          <p className="lead text-muted">{user.email}</p>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Highlight>{JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</Highlight>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticationRequired(ProfileComponent, {
  onRedirecting: () => <Loading />,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I created one Azure AD application and assigned **API permissions** like below:

[image]

In Token configuration, I added both ***family_name*** and ***given_name*** like below:

[image]

Before generating the access token, please check whether the **user** has both attributes **`updated`** or not like below:

[image]

To get **`code`** for access token, I used below authorization request:

```http
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<application_id>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=openid profile user.read
&state=12345
```

When I ran the above request in browser, I got **`code`** in ***address bar*** after authenticating successfully like below:

[image]

I generated the **access token** via Postman using below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:<application_id>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:openid profile user.read
client_secret:secret
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code: code from above request
```

**Response:**

[image]

I decoded the above access token in **[jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms/)** and got below claims:

[image]

When I used the above token to get **`user's profile`** with this query, I got both ***family_name*** and ***given_name*** like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure whether the **`signed in user`** has both ***family_name*** and ***given_name*** properties updated in their profiles or not.

Please check whether the access token includes  ***family_name*** and ***given_name*** claims or not by decoding it.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a very detailed answer, and very clearly pointed things, I also found out that if the user has only an admin role, then can get the token,